# Is there a field with $n$ elements for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: finite-fields

I don't think this is true, but I'm not sure. I certainly know of finite fields with 2,4 and 8 elements, and of course $p^n$ elements where $p$ is prime, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Nope. Hint: in a finite field, consider the subfield generated by $1$. This is called the _prime subfield_. Any field is a vector space over its prime subfield...

Comment: Please ask one question per post. If you believe that several questions are sufficiently related to warrant asking them in one post, please point out where you see the connection.

Comment: @joriki Okay, I'll make separate posts.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be a field of order $n$ and $P$ its prime subfield. Then $P\cong \mathbb Z_p$ where $p = \lvert P \rvert$. Thus $p$ is prime. So now $F$ is a finite $P$ vector space, and thus $n = \lvert F \rvert = \lvert P \rvert ^k = p^k$, where $k = \operatorname{dim}_P (F)$.